# How to hide form code from view code/inspect element browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I want to hide form code from view code/inspect element browser , how can i do that ?

This is my code, please see below:

```
<div style=" text-align: center;  padding: 300px; font-family: lato; ">
     Please wait redirect page ......<br>
    <img src="http://maps.nrel.gov/sites/all/modules/custom_modules/hydra/assets/images/loading_bar.gif" border="0">
</div>


<form name="f1" action="payments.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id_crad" value="...">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.99">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){f1.submit();}, 3000);
</script>
```

Please see picture

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you're using a compiled language (eg. A Java web applet, Flash [easy to decompile], etc).

Comment: You can't. Thankfully. Do you really want to lose the ability to see what websites are doing to you?

Comment: can i cover my code with php tag ?

Comment: No. Curl the form instead

Comment: You can easily hide code from prying eyes by not including it in any web page.

Comment: RobG ---  please show example

Comment: you cant hide that, your browser already shows what it can do. why not put that values on the server instead

Answer (score 41):

You simply can't.

Code inspectors are designed for debugging HTML and JavaScript. They do so by showing the live DOM object of the web page. That means it reveals HTML code of everything you see on the page, even if they're generated by JavaScript. Some inspectors even shows the code inside Iframes.

#### How about some JavaScript to disable keyboard / mouse interaction...

There are some JavaScript tricks to disable some keyboard, mouse interaction on the page. But there **always** are work around to those tricks. For instance, you can use the browser top menu to enable DOM inspector without a problem.

Try theses:

- Firefox: [☰ > Tools > Web Developer > Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector)
- Chrome: [⋮ > More Tools > Developer Tools > Elements](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open)

They are outside the control of JavaScript.

#### Big Picture

Think about this:

1. **Everything** on a web page is rendered by the browser, so they are of a lower abstraction level than your JavaScript. They are "guarding all the doors and holding all the keys".
2. Browsers **want** web sites to properly work on them or their users would despise them.
3. As a result, browsers **want** to expose the lower level ticks of **everything** to the web developers with tools like code inspectors.

Basically, browsers are god to your JavaScript. And they want to grant the web developer super power with code inspectors. Even if your trick works for a while, the browsers would want to undo it in the future.

You're waging war against god and you're doomed to fail.

### Conclusion

To put it simple, if you do not want people to get something in their browser, you should **never** send it to their browser in the first place.

Comment: What an absolute statement to make.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, that absolute statement is true. There are some javascript tricks to disable some keyboard, mouse interaction on the page. But there are always work around to those tricks. For instance, you can use the browser top menu to enable DOM inspector without a problem.

Comment: To put it simple, if you do not want people to get something in their browser, you should never send it to their browser in the first place.

Comment: What about @dihak's answer below it seems that it does the trick

Comment: @AhmedAbuthwabah: You can checkout the comments to his answer. Not all browsers "support" that workaround. And since it is not an intended "feature" of a browser, you should not expect it to keep working on those browsers that "support" it, as I described in the "Big Picture",

Answer (score 24):

There is a smart way to disable inspect element in your website. Just add the following snippet inside script tag :

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

Please check out this [blog](http://developersdigest.blogspot.in/2013/10/disable-inspect-elementsource-viewing.html)

The function key F12 which directly take inspect element from browser, we can also disable it, by using the following code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 123){
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It only disable the right click and inspect element option , will allow f12 and directly take inspect element from browser, and the reality is you can't disable it .

Comment: Well, if we can disable all key events, then it is possible. Just try the following code.  $('*').off('keyup keydown keypress');

Comment: that is not the right way to do that, never restrict any key event from our code the user may be used those keys for someother purpose so we cannot do that .Also if we are disable the key events using the code given by you then also we can take inspect element directly from browser,it is a feature provided by browser so how can we restrict that??

Comment: You are right we cant disable all the key events, but we can just disable the function keys, then it would be ok. It is our need to hide the code. For that purpose, I think, it is ok to disable F12.

Comment: function keys are used in various purposes not only for inspect elements so how we can do that?? also if u did that then how will you restrict inspect element option directly from the browser??

Comment: There are various purposes for function keys, but what I meant is to disable function keys on the current page or the page which the developer wants to hide from user. There are so many sites which disable page source and inspect element feature. It may be unprofessional, but there are people practicing it and it is possible.

Comment: Still you can open Chrome inspector from menu. It's worthless.

Comment: What if an evil mind person disable the javascript from browser the above code will fail.

Comment: How about `Ctrl` + `Shift`+ `i` ?

Comment: Just a question about this topic. What will happen if you use the firefox and chrome plugin "noscript"?

Answer (score 17):

You can add this script to make a error when user inpect :D

Try this code

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('(3(){(3 a(){8{(3 b(2){7((\'\'+(2/2)).6!==1||2%5===0){(3(){}).9(\'4\')()}c{4}b(++2)})(0)}d(e){g(a,f)}})()})();',17,17,'||i|function|debugger|20|length|if|try|constructor|||else|catch||5000|setTimeout'.split('|'),0,{}))
</script>
```

From http://www.bloggerku.com/2017/08/memasang-anti-inspect.html

Comment: I already encountered this one on a website while attempting to inspect element. `(function() {}).constructor('debugger')()` and `setTimeout` do the trick 

Comment: Doesn't work on Chrome. It does show an error but can easily view and edit the inspect elements.

Comment: It create difficulty to inspect the source but not impossible. but I disabled indexedDB by this code.

Comment: I see some websites hide their m3u8 how can they do that?

Answer (score 15):

You can use this code -

Block Right Click -

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

Block Keys - You should use this on the upper of the body tag. (use in the head tag)

```
<script>

    document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        if (event.keyCode == 123) {
            return false;
        }
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && (e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0) || e.keyCode == 'i'.charCodeAt(0))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && (e.keyCode == 'C'.charCodeAt(0) || e.keyCode == 'c'.charCodeAt(0))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && (e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0) || e.keyCode == 'j'.charCodeAt(0))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0) || e.keyCode == 'u'.charCodeAt(0))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == 'S'.charCodeAt(0) || e.keyCode == 's'.charCodeAt(0))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

This code removes the inner html of an element from the dom when the debugger is open (tested in Chrome and IE)

```
var currentInnerHtml;
var element = new Image();
var elementWithHiddenContent = document.querySelector("#element-to-hide");
var innerHtml = elementWithHiddenContent.innerHTML;

element.__defineGetter__("id", function() {
    currentInnerHtml = "";
});

setInterval(function() {
    currentInnerHtml = innerHtml;
    console.log(element);
    console.clear();
    elementWithHiddenContent.innerHTML = currentInnerHtml;
}, 1000);
```

Here `#element-to-hide` is the id of element you want to hide.
It is a hack, but I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't think there is a way to fully do this you can take a few measures to stop almost everyone from viewing the HTML.

You can first of all try and stop the inspect menu by doing the following:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false" onkeydown="return false;" onmousedown="return false;">
```

I would also suggest using the method that ***Jonas*** gave of using his javascript and putting what you don't want people to see in a *div* with ***id="element-to-hide"*** and his given js script to furthermore stop people from inspecting.

I'm pretty sure that it's quite hard to get past that. But then someone can just type ***view-source:www.exapmle.com*** and that will show them the source. So you will then probably want to encrypt the HTML(I would advise using a website that gives you an extended security option). There are plenty of good websites that do this for free (eg:http://www.smartgb.com/free_encrypthtml.php) and use extended security which you can't usually unencrypt through HTML un encryptors.

This will basically encrypt your HTML so if you view the source using the method I showed above you will just get encrypted HTML(that is also extremely difficult to unencrypt if you used the extended security option). But you can view the unencrypted HTML through inspecting but we have already blocked that(to a very reasonable extent)

> Ok so you can't fully hide the HTML but you can do an extremely good
>   job at stopping people seeing it.(If you think about it most people
>   don't care about looking at a page's HTML, some people don't even know
>   about inspecting and viewing the source and the people who do probably
>   won't be bothered or won't be able to get past theses implications! So
>   probably no one will see you HTML)

(Hope this helps!)

Answer (score 2):

Below JavaScript code worked for me to disable inspect element.

```
// Disable inspect element
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
});
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 123){
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: above code only disable right click and F12 key?

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think there is a way to fully do this you can take a few measures to stop almost everyone from viewing the HTML.

You can first of all try and stop the inspect menu by doing the following:

I would also suggest using the method that Jonas gave of using his javascript and putting what you don't want people to see in a div with id="element-to-hide" and his given js script to furthermore stop people from inspecting.

I'm pretty sure that it's quite hard to get past that. But then someone can just type view-source

This will basically encrypt your HTML so if you view the source using the method I showed above you will just get encrypted HTML(that is also extremely difficult to unencrypt if you used the extended security option). But you can view the unencrypted HTML through inspecting but we have already blocked that(to a very reasonable extent)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following tag

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false"><!-- your page body hear--></body>
```

OR you can create your own menu when right click:

https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu

Answer (score 0):

you can not stop user from seeing our code but you can avoid it by disabling some keys

simply you can do `<body oncontextmenu="return false" onkeydown="return false;" onmousedown="return false;"><!--Your body context--> </body>`

After doing this following keys get disabled automatically

**1. Ctrl + Shift + U
 2. Ctrl + Shift + C
 3. Ctrl + Shift + I
 4. Right Click of mouse
 5. F12 Key**

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think there is a way to fully do this you can take a few measures to stop almost everyone from viewing the HTML.

You can first of all try and stop the inspect menu by doing the following:

I would also suggest using the method that Jonas gave of using his javascript and putting what you don't want people to see in a div with id="element-to-hide" and his given js script to furthermore stop people from inspecting.

I'm pretty sure that it's quite hard to get past that. But then someone can just type view-source:www.exapmle.com and that will show them the source. So you will then probably want to encrypt the HTML(I would advise using a website that gives you an extended security option). There are plenty of good websites that do this for free (eg:http://www.smartgb.com/free_encrypthtml.php) and use extended security which you can't usually unencrypt through HTML un encryptors.

This will basically encrypt your HTML so if you view the source using the method I showed above you will just get encrypted HTML(that is also extremely difficult to unencrypt if you used the extended security option). But you can view the unencrypted HTML through inspecting but we have already blocked that(to a very reasonable extent)

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
if(event.keyCode == 123) {
return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'E'.charCodeAt(0)){
return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)){
return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0)){
return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0)){
return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'S'.charCodeAt(0)){
return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'H'.charCodeAt(0)){
return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'A'.charCodeAt(0)){
return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'E'.charCodeAt(0)){
return false;
}
}
</script>
```

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

if someones is interested you can delete the form node from the DOM after the submission and it won't be there using the inspector.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging for your question and found an intriguing idea by [PwnFunction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msdymgkhePo&t=458s).

If you can fit your complete code into your CSS file. Then we can use the response header "[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers#:%7E:text=a%20large%20allocation.-,Link,-The)" to link your CSS file to your request for the site.

According to MDN Docs:

> HTTP headers let the client and the server pass additional information
> with an HTTP request or response. An HTTP header consists of its
> case-insensitive name followed by a colon (:), then by its value.
> Whitespace before the value is ignored.

> The Link entity-header field provides a means for serializing one or more
> links in HTTP headers. It is semantically equivalent to the HTML link
> element.

So this header can link your stylesheet to your HTTP request. So what will happen in the backend is that whenever someone tries to "inspect element" your source code, they'll see a blank page for your HTML code. But they can still see the link to your stylesheet in developer tools.