# How to hide HTML from F12 & inspect element, sers should not be able to edit my disabled fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please help me, in my application I will have enabled and disabled fields depending on conditions but when I press f12 I am able to edit disabled fields also so I have implemented a small hack kind of implementation but not sure if it is better approach
Please suggest me any better approach

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Profile</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">                                                                    
    </style>

    <script>
    function divFunction(user){
        event.preventDefault();   
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:'publicProfile.action?userNbk='+user,
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                document.getElementById("userNameHeader").innerHTML = obj.articleUserName;
                document.getElementById("publicEmail").innerHTML = obj.articleUserEmail;
                document.getElementById("publicNbk").innerHTML = obj.articleUserNbk;
                document.getElementById("publicPid").innerHTML = obj.articleUserPersonId;
                document.getElementById("publicGender").innerHTML = obj.articleUserGender;
                document.getElementById("publicJob").innerHTML = obj.articleUserOccupation;
                document.getElementById("publicAddress").innerHTML = obj.articleUserAddress;
                document.getElementById("publicIntrests").innerHTML = obj.articleUserIntrests;
           }}); 
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function isConsoleOpen() {
        alert("hello");
          var startTime = new Date();
          debugger;
          var endTime = new Date();
          return endTime - startTime > 10;
        }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("helo");  
        if(isConsoleOpen()) {
            /* alert("You're one sneaky dude, aren't you ?") */
            document.getElementById("aaaaaa").innerHTML="You're one sneaky dude, aren't you ?";
        }
    })

    $(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode==123){
    return false;
   }
    else if(event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode==73){        
      return false;  //Prevent from ctrl+shift+i
   }
});
    $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="aaaaaa">
    <form>
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled">
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled">
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled">
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“I have implemented a small hack kind of implementation”_ — Please [edit] your question and explain what your hack actually is and what it does. “Better” in what sense? You could maybe attach a `click` listener to the element which changes a local variable in some function reflecting the state of it. That variable is then used for whatever you need. If that function is inaccessible from outside, you might get close to preventing those things.

Comment: Always use server-side validation. You can't stop users from using browser dev tools, or from bypassing the browser entirely and calling your URL from some other tool. (Also, testing whether the console is open at the moment the page loads doesn't tell you anything useful.)

Answer (score 14):

To specifically answer your question, there is no way to keep users from editing your disabled fields.  It is impossible to keep users from viewing **and editing** your HTML.

The **only** thing you can do to truly take care of this issue is to use ***server-side validation***.  If there is a field you don't want text passed into, you're just going to have to set up some kind of validation on the server side to not process the data from that field.  Unfortunately, that's just a part of web development.

Creating "hacky" solutions is **not** a good idea.  It leads to unmanageable code, and in this case, it does not even solve the issue.

In fact, (and yes this is opinion-based) I would even say it *encourages* people to mess with your fields, because if I were hunting around in your code and I saw you *trying* to keep me out, the first thing I'm going to do is try to get around your hacky block.  And 100 times out of 100, I'm going to succeed.

Comment: @ Kyle Martin, You are gonna definitely help me

Comment: could you please say how you are going to get around my code so that I can improve that code to stop you
could you please explain in elaborate

Comment: In Google Chrome:  1)  Open the webpage.  2)  Click the Chrome menu (three dots)  3)  Hover over "More Tools".  4)  Click "Developer Tools".   Done.  I'm in, and I can edit your fields however I want.  :)

Comment: Trying to implement a solution to block that too

Comment: please let me know if there are any other ways
Thanks in advance

Comment: There aren't.  You simple cannot prevent people from editing HTML.  Sorry.

Answer (score 10):

Preventing HTML from being seen and/or edited is impossible.

Comment: Ultimately, it does. `How to hide HTML from F12 & inspect element, sers should not be able to edit my disabled fields` - It can't be done. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24319844