# Hiding button value from inspect element

Tags: php, html, button, passwords

I am working to create a new method to login. I need to use plenty of button which contain value inside it to pass to js and js will put all the button value clicked into a html input type="password". My question is how to hide the button value from viewable? As i know inspect element can view the content easily. Beside disable right click those, any more idea or method. Thanks.

Comment: What value are you trying to "hide"? In what way are you trying to reinvent the wheel in creating login methods? Why not take the password the user supplies, hash using the same method as its stored in the database, and compare against that? I guess what I'm trying to say is you didn't supply enough information, but the information you did provide makes me wonder about what you're trying to accomplish... :)

Comment: I agree with @LucasKrupinski , you should just take the password in plain text and then hash it when it gets to the server and compare it to your stored password. You shouldn't be doing anything client side (i.e. in the browser) that makes hiding the button value necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide HTML elements in "inspect element" or "source-code".

I believe [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319786/how-to-hide-form-code-from-view-code-inspect-element-browser) asked the same thing.