# how to hide html code when inspecting in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

```
    $content .= '</td><td style=" text-align:left !important;"><p>' 
. $boardCodeAndName[$room['BoardOption']] . '</p></td><td><b>&pound;' 
. round($cost_per_person) . '</b></td><td><input onClick="avg_value(' 
. $final_hotel_count . ',' . $cost_per_person 
. ');" type="radio" name="hotel_' . $final_hotel_count 
. $final_room_count . '" class="hotel_' . $final_hotel_count
```

this is my code how to hide this  when i am inspecting.

Comment: 1) Show us what you tried; 2) Please edit your code so it looks like code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide form code from view code/inspect element browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319786/how-to-hide-form-code-from-view-code-inspect-element-browser)

Comment: First of all think that is it possible ? Is without any HTML any web page can work?

Comment: Do you mean that the code is inspected in Codeigniter or simply that the site is made _using_ Codeigniter? Hiding it from browsers inspect-view isn't possible.

Comment: You kind of need to answer peoples questions if you're expecting them to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
if(event.keyCode == 123) {
return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)){
return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0)){
return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0)){
return false;
}
if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'C'.charCodeAt(0)){
return false;
}

}
```

Comment: 1.this code will not allow F12,CTRL+SHIFT+U,CTRL+SHIFT+I,CTRL+SHIFT+J and CTRL+SHIFT+C

Answer (score 2):

### How to hide HTML code when inspecting?

This given option will disable the inspecting on the page.

1. Script for disable the Right click on the page:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
       });
   </script>
   ```
2. Enable the key F12 from the keyboard to open inspect.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).keydown(function(e){
           if(e.which === 123){
              return false;
           }
       });
   </script>
   ```

this code will work in Codeigniter. Just put it inside `<script>` tag and put that at the end of your page.