# Detect user inspect and remove entire div

Tags: javascript, html

Using following script I can make a error when user inpect on web browser. Within following script, can I delete entire div element when user trying to inpect on web browser?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('(3(){(3 a(){8{(3 b(2){7((\'\'+(2/2)).6!==1||2%5===0){(3(){}).9(\'4\')()}c{4}b(++2)})(0)}d(e){g(a,f)}})()})();',17,17,'||i|function|debugger|20|length|if|try|constructor|||else|catch||5000|setTimeout'.split('|'),0,{}))
</script>
```

Comment: Where did you find this script? Does it come with some documentation maybe?

Comment: @sjahan from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319786/how-to-hide-form-code-from-view-code-inspect-element-browser/24320533

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of malicious intent.

Comment: @AndrewL Actually I don't know what happens inside that script. I got that one from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319786/how-to-hide-form-code-from-view-code-inspect-element-browser/24320533

Comment: @isuru Just as one of the users in your provided link rightly said, `To put it simple, if you do not want people to get something in their browser, you should never send it to their browser in the first place.`

Comment: Even if you could disable the dev tools, one interested user still could sniff the HTTP response with another tool than the browser and get the HTML. You cannot really protect it.

Comment: @sjahan Is my above script malicious?

Comment: @isuru I don't know and I don't want to try it ;) `eval` is evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect whether dev tools is opened or not use [this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect) library.

```
<script src="node_modules/devtools-detect/index.js"></script>
<script>
    // check if it's open
    console.log('is DevTools open?', window.devtools.open);
    // check it's orientation, null if not open
    console.log('and DevTools orientation?', window.devtools.orientation);

    // get notified when it's opened/closed or orientation changes
    window.addEventListener('devtoolschange', function (e) {
        console.log('is DevTools open?', e.detail.open);
        console.log('and DevTools orientation?', e.detail.orientation);
    });
</script>
```