# How to hide html content from inspect element of developer tools?

Tags: javascript, html, inspect-element

I have disabled both right click and keyboard events from accessing the insoect element but it still can be used through the developer tools of chrome browser. Is there any way to hide the html code from being edited in inspect element.

Comment: There is no such way to do that. Regardless, as soon as you move to the client side, it does not matter whether you disable right/left clicks etc., you are always going to be vulnerable to users viewing your code. That is why you move sensitive stuff to the backend. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559409/how-to-disable-browser-developer-tools

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide form code from view code/inspect element browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319786/how-to-hide-form-code-from-view-code-inspect-element-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot secure your front-end, but you can certainly secure your server-side!

Good luck