# Is there a possible way to hide the input from inspect element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input that is hidden and I don't want it to be shown in inspect element. Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide form code from view code/inspect element browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319786/how-to-hide-form-code-from-view-code-inspect-element-browser)

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Why do you find the need to hide an element from the inspector? Also, everything that you send to the client will be accessible by the client.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. Any HTML element will be accessible through the HTML source, even if generated dynamically through javascript.

If you are trying to secure some information which the client should not have access to, do not send it to the client.